# Count in subquery is removing null values - how do I include them? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that gives me the expected results but i'm getting the results pictured on the right

I wrote a subquery that counts which country_codes appear more than once but it is excluding null values which isn't giving me the right results. Does anyone know how I can alter my query to include the expected results?

[Expected results(left) vs Actual results(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdY9D.png)

```
select ifnull(country_code,"N/A") as country_codes, continent_code
    from continent_map
    where country_code
    IN (
        SELECT country_code
        from continent_map
        group by country_code
        having count(country_code) > 1)
    
    order by field(country_codes,"N/A") DESC
```

Comment: On a side note: Be careful with the quotes. Use single quotes for strings. Double quotes are for names in SQL and confusing the two can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `IFNULL(country_code,"N/A")` everywhere instead of single `country_code`:

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(country_code,"N/A") AS country_codes, 
       continent_code
FROM continent_map
WHERE IFNULL(country_code,"N/A") IN ( 
        SELECT IFNULL(country_code,"N/A")
        FROM continent_map
        GROUP BY country_code
        HAVING COUNT(IFNULL(country_code,"N/A")) > 1
)
ORDER BY FIELD(country_codes,"N/A") DESC
```

You must guarantee that `"N/A"` is absent in `country_code` column (or, if it is present, it is treated as the same value as NULL).

If `"N/A"` is really absent in `country_code` column then you may use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` - but this shouldn't effect anything, including the performance.

Comment: Its not needed to ensure that N/A entry is absent in country_code, it should get treated separately, as its NOT a NULL value. NULL denotes the absence of value, which gets sorted at the top of the result set, while N/A is an entry which is NOT NULL

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph But `IFNULL(country_code,"N/A")` collapses NULL and N/A rows into one group. This may result in an effect when single NULL and single N/A rows will be returned due to they're counted together and hence they'd match HAVING condition. If this is not needed effect, and these values must be counted separately then some another placeholder instead of N/A must be used.

Answer (score 0):

You would edit the query to use count(*) as Tim as mentioned.  Next to get the nulls on top we can order by as follows.

```
select ifnull(country_code,"N/A") as country_codes, continent_code
    from continent_map
    where ifnull(country_code,'-1')
    IN (
        SELECT ifnull(country_code,'-1')
        from continent_map
        group by country_code
        having count(*) > 1)
    order by country_code is null desc,country_code asc
```

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e76c9d4b733ca83b00067e611dbd1e80

Comment: I have corrected to use count(*) in the group by clause

Comment: You are right i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

`IN` doesn't find NULLs. And `COUNT(NULL)` is 0 anyway. If you want to count rows use `COUNT(*)`.

The easiest approach is probably to replace NULLs by N/A right away:

```
WITH countries AS
(
  SELECT COALESCE(country_code, 'N/A') AS country_code, continent_code
  FROM continent_map
)
SELECT country_code, continent_code
FROM countries
WHERE country_code
IN (
      SELECT country_code
      FROM countries
      GROUP BY country_code
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
ORDER BY field(country_code, 'N/A') DESC, country_code, continent_code;
```

Here is the same thing shorter by using the window function `COUNT OVER`:

```
SELECT country_code, continent_code
FROM
(
  SELECT COALESCE(country_code, 'N/A') AS country_code,
  continent_code,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_code) as cnt
  FROM continent_map
) counted
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY field(country_code, 'N/A') DESC, country_code, continent_code;
```